# CSS Mask a line

Tags: css

Okay, i am not allowed to upload an image yet, so i will try to explain it this way:

I am trying to create this effect:

(**update**: text replaced with an image)
[image]

= : background div with background-image

the dashed line has a width of 100% and does not cross the name.

I don't want the line to go over the name, so 
i am looking for some kind of mask that i can place
over the line.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: 1) What have you tried? 2) If you upload the imgur and post the link, we can embed it in your question.

Comment: I really haven't tried anything yet.. I first had a color as background so i simply gave the name the same color as background

Comment: here is a sample: http://imgur.com/Cup87Iq

Comment: StackOverflow is not a 'do my homework for me' kind of website. its a website where developers turn to for help if they get stuck coding something and need assistance. please show some effort on your side, and try to code it yourself first. then, if you get stuck we will be happy to assist

Comment: I don't usually post anything on StackOverflow but right now i don't know where to start

Comment: Once again … http://css-tricks.com/line-on-sides-headers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the line with `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, styled with a border:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 3px double;
  /* You can add a backgound here */
}
#wrapper::before, #wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-top: 1px dashed;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>Peter</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with flexbox.

Here is an [example on codepen](http://codepen.io/positlabs/pen/ByYYvV)

```
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: lightgray;
}

.wrapper div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.line {
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  top: 7px;
}

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <span>hello</span>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `z-index` in the css.
Let the upper layer get the larger number.